# How does glue identify rds tinyint types as ints

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, aws-glue

Recently, I am synchronizing the data table in RDS to redshift through glue.

Example Mysql Table:

| column | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | int | 1 |
| deleted | tinyint(1) | 0 |
| count | tinyint(1) | 5 |

When I apply mapping like this below:

```
(id, int, id, int),
(deleted, boolean, deleted, boolean),
(age, tinyint, age, tinyint)
```

redshift table got like this

| column | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | int | 1 |
| deleted | boolean | false |
| count | **smallint** | **NULL** |

As u can ses, the data for column count is lost and type got modified, and i've tested many different mappings i know, still unresolved.

Already read this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/federated-data-types.html